# How to extract matrices from QtOctave to LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, octave

I have a large matrices created using QtOctave which is simply impossible to rewrite it to spreadsheet program, just using copy-paste won't put each number into separate cell. How do I export these matrices to LO Calc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the octave `csvwrite` or `dlmwrite` to write your matrix to a comma-separated variable file, which you can open / import into LibreOffice Calc

```
csvwrite('mymat.csv', m)
```

or equivalently

```
dlmwrite('mymat.csv', m, ',')
```

Comment: Sorry but how exactly I do that? I don't do any octave project and never used octave before, I use QtOctave just to extract color information of high res black and white image using [matrixbmp]=imread('image.bmp') command, now I want to export the matrix to spreadsheet program so I can make histogram of that image. Can you provide me with step by step procedure?

Comment: If matrixbmp is the name of your matrix, and you want to save it to a CSV file called 'data.csv', you would type at the octave command prompt (>>>) the line `csvwrite('data.csv',matrixbmp)`